# Can I extract the subclass instance of an abstract class from a Type parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, implicit

I have a class structure like the one below:

```
sealed trait A 

case class A1 extends A
case class A2 extends A
case class A3 extends A 

sealed trait B[T <: A]

case class B1 extends B[A1]
case class B2 extends B[A2]
case class B3 extends B[A3]

class C[T <: A](val b: B[T])
```

every subclass of `B[T]` matches 1 to 1 to its subclass of `A`.

```
val b1 = new B1() 
val c1 = new C[A1](b1)
```

(my structure is a little more complicated since I have implicit factories for `B[T]` so for the apply function for `C[T]` it can implicitly locate the factory and create the instance of `B[T]`)

If I were to do `val t = c1.b`, `t` would be type `B[A1]`. 
Is there a way to extract the subclass of `B[T]` so that `c1.b` was type `B1`? I do not want to have to define another type parameter because all the information is in the type of `A`. Essentially I want `C` to know the type of `B[T]` based on the type of `A` provided.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to convince the compiler that given the type of `A` it should infer the type of `B`.

Maybe if you expand a little bit more on your use case there could be another way using type classes.
But for now, this should work.

```
class C[T <: A, U](val b: U)
                  (implicit ev: U <:< B[T])
```